# Trigger click event using parentsUntil or without it in a treeview to search nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a treeview with following structure, I would like to expand tree nodes to select a specific node by id.

I have reached to this stage where I can get to parentUntil but I am not sure how to use it trigger click events or change classes of parent's sibling's childrens,

- How can I trigger click event on divs with class "col" using or without using parentsUtil function

Here is the fiddle: www.jsfiddle.net/m3hecxyr

This is what I have am trying,

```
$("a[href='#id=4'").parentsUntil($("#list > ul")) // what's next ?
```

**Structure**

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <div class="col" onclick="toggle(this);" />
        <div class="icon" />
        <a href="#id=1">A</a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="col" onclick="toggle(this);" />
            <div class="icon" />
            <a href="#id=2">A.1</a>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <div class="icon" />
                <a href="#id=3">A.1.1</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <div class="icon" />
                <a href="#id=4">A.1.2</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <div class="icon" />
            <a href="#id=5">B</a>
          </div>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <div class="icon" />
          <a href="#id=6">C</a>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want [`$('a[href="#id=4"]').closest('#list').children('ul').css('border', '1px solid red');`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/m3hecxyr/1/)? Just `$('#list > ul').css(` will work too.

Comment: @Tushar I don't want to add border, I want to change css classes or trigger click events on them, I improved my question, does it makes sense now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to make it work myself using code below,

```
$("a[href='#id=4'").parentsUntil($("#list > ul" )).each(function() {
    if($(this).is("li"))
         $($(this).find(".exp").get(0)).trigger("click")
});
```

I am not sure if there is any better way out but this is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I trigger click event on divs with class "col" using or without using parentsUtil function

If you intend to click on the div element with col class related to the current subtree, you need to go up to the closest element having a div with such a class and from there find the corresponding div:

```
$("a[href='#id=4']").closest($("ul:has(div.col)")).find ('div.col').get(0).click();
```

Your toggle function is not described so I would suggest to implement that as:

```
function toggle(ele, evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    ele.classList.toggle('col');
    ele.classList.toggle('exp');
}
```

And for the inline call:

```
toggle(this, event);
```

The snippet:

```js
function toggle(ele, evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  evt.stopPropagation();
  ele.classList.toggle('col');
  ele.classList.toggle('exp');
}
$(function () {

  $("a[href='#id=4']")
      .closest($("ul:has(div.col)"))
          .find ('div.col').get(0).click();

});
```

```css
.col {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.exp {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div class="col" onclick="toggle(this, event);" />
                <div class="icon" />
                <a href="#id=1">A</a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col" onclick="toggle(this, event);" />
                        <div class="icon" />
                        <a href="#id=2">A.1</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <div class="icon" />
                                <a href="#id=3">A.1.1</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <div class="icon" />
                                <a href="#id=4">A.1.2</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <div class="icon" />
                        <a href="#id=5">B</a>
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div class="icon" />
                <a href="#id=6">C</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I tried your example but it didn't helped so I came up with my own answer